# 'SessionStore' object has no attribute 'GET'

Tags: python, django

What is wrong in this code, it generates the following error:

```
>   'SessionStore' object has no attribute 'GET'
```

this is the code:

```
def blog_detail(request, blog_slug):
    blog = get_object_or_404(Blog, slug=blog_slug)
    session_key = 'blog_views_{}'.format(blog.slug)
    if not request.session.GET.get('session_key', False)
        blog.blog_views += 1
        blog.save()
        request.session['session_key'] = True

    return render(request, 'blogs/blog-detail.html', {'blog':blog})
```

I think I am doing it wrong using `request.session`. Can you help me with that, Thank you.

edit: traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/dramatically-productivate-global-functionalities-whereas-reliable-internal-or-organic-sources

Django Version: 2.2.1
Python Version: 3.7.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'blogs',
 'users',
 'crispy_forms']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "E:\Practice\new-blog\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "E:\Practice\new-blog\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "E:\Practice\new-blog\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "E:\Practice\new-blog\src\blogs\views.py" in blog_detail
  53.     if not request.session.GET.get('session_key', False):

Exception Type: AttributeError at /dramatically-productivate-global-functionalities-whereas-reliable-internal-or-organic-sources
Exception Value: 'SessionStore' object has no attribute 'GET'
```

Comment: You forgot a colon (`:`) at the end of the `if` statement.

Comment: Furthermore you obtain the session key with `request.session.pk`.

Comment: yes, thank you. I get another error. Question updated.

Comment: Can you please show the *full* traceback?

Comment: Yes, I just added it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors here:

- you can not use `request.session.GET.get(..)` since a `SessionBase` object has *no* `GET` attribute; and
- You used a *string literal* `'session_key'` instead of the identifier.

You probably want to write:

```
def blog_detail(request, blog_slug):
    blog = get_object_or_404(Blog, slug=blog_slug)
    session_key = 'blog_views_{}'.format(blog.slug)
    if not request.session.get(session_key, False):
        blog.blog_views += 1
        blog.save()
        request.session[session_key] = True

    return render(request, 'blogs/blog-detail.html', {'blog':blog})
```

we can make the `if` statement a bit shorter, since `.get(..)` by default returns `None` which has truthiness `False` as well:

```
def blog_detail(request, blog_slug):
    blog = get_object_or_404(Blog, slug=blog_slug)
    session_key = 'blog_views_{}'.format(blog.slug)
    if not request.session.get(session_key):
        blog.blog_views += 1
        blog.save()
        request.session[session_key] = True

    return render(request, 'blogs/blog-detail.html', {'blog':blog})
```

So here we use `request.session.get(..)` and use the `session_key` identifier, not a literal. If we would use `'session_key'` we simply ask if the session has a key `'session_key'`, not the `'blog_views_some-title'`.